# Update multiple rows in Informix SQL

Tags: sql, database, informix

I'm trying update roughly 20k lines for a storage sequence

Here's what the data looks like

Table: lc_f

```
 -------------------
|Loc      |store_seq|
|BGB011   |82600    |
|BGB012   |82610    |
|BGB021   |82640    |
|BGB022   |82650    |
|BGB031   |82680    |
|BGB032   |82690    |
---------------------
```

I'm wanting to update all store_seq with one update query, in an increment of 2 (for simplicity I'll start at 1)

Here's what I want it to look like afterwards.

```
-------------------
|Loc      |store_seq|
|BGB011   |00001    |
|BGB012   |00003    |
|BGB021   |00005    |
|BGB022   |00007    |
|BGB031   |00009    |
|BGB032   |00011    |
---------------------
```

Any help would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using?  Is it 12.10, 11.70 or some other version?  Is a stored procedure an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be better ways to do it, but this simple-minded brute force stored procedure should do the job:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_lc_f_sequence_numbers()
    DEFINE v_loc CHAR(10);
    DEFINE v_seq INTEGER;
    BEGIN WORK;
    SELECT Loc FROM lc_f INTO TEMP t_lc_f_sequence_numbers;
    LET v_seq = 1;
    FOREACH SELECT Loc INTO v_loc FROM t_lc_f_sequence_numbers ORDER BY Loc
        UPDATE lc_f SET Store_Seq = v_seq WHERE Loc = v_loc;
        LET v_seq = v_seq + 2;
    END FOREACH;
    DROP TABLE t_lc_f_sequence_numbers;
    COMMIT WORK;
END PROCEDURE;
```

The tricky part of any processing is getting the sequence numbers applied to the correctly sequenced 'loc' values.  This makes a copy of the loc values in a temporary table (originally, I used `t`, but that's not really distinct enough), then selects the values in sequence and runs the update statement once per row, adjusting the sequence number each time.  This isn't as devastating for performance as it would be in a client program because the data is not sent between client and server; it is all available in the server.

The use of transaction statements should be considered carefully.  If the database is unlogged, they'll have to be omitted.  If the database is logged, then you might already be in a transaction, in which case the BEGIN WORK would fail.  You could use exception handling to identify this and continue, leaving whatever code started the transaction to finish it (so the COMMIT WORK would not be executed if the BEGIN WORK failed).  You could consider using a SAVEPOINT instead of a full transaction.  You probably want some sort of transaction handling so that the changes are rolled back if there's a problem part way through the processing.

There might be a way to do something with the OLAP functions and ROW_NUMBER() — or maybe `ROW_NUMBER() * 2 - 1` — but I'm not sufficiently sure of how to do it.  This should work with more or less any Informix version you can lay hands on; the OLAP functions are only available in IDS 12.10 (and maybe some later 11.70 fix packs).

<sup>*Caution: code not run — but the stored procedure was created successfully, even though the database did not contain a table `lc_f`.*</sup>

Comment: Hey, I'm using informix 11.50. So I can definitely use this, but the reasoning behind the iterations is I'm trying to do a middle out approach. so all the odd numbers would be expanding to the left and the even's are expanding to the right. I planned on updating the sequence one aisle at a time. Could I just update your sql select statement to set the parameters? for example.   `SELECT Loc FROM lc_f WHERE substr(loc,1,3) = 'BGB' and substr(loc,6,1) in ('1','2') INTO TEMP t_lc_f_sequence_numbers;`

Comment: Yes, you can control which `Loc` values are updated by modifying the criteria associated with the `SELECT … INTO TEMP` statement.  You can tune the assigned values by specifying start and increment (or by more complex mechanisms — maybe using a SEQUENCE).  If you need a different order than raw `Loc` values in sorted order, you can add columns to the temporary table such that you can order by those, and then modify the FOREACH loop accordingly.  There are endless adaptations that can be made to make it do more exactly what you need it to do.

Comment: So I'm running the procedure, and it executes but say's no rows affected. I thought maybe it was a case issue with the Loc and loc but that didn't resolve it.

Comment: I decided to break it down step by step and it imports the data into the t_lc_f_sequence_numbers table but for some reason the FOREACH loop isn't working.